# Helm pod for mongodb crashing on startup

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm trying to start a helm pod using bitnami and mongodb. This is my .yaml file

```
architecture: standalone
useStatefulSet: true

persistence:
  size: 20Gi
  existingClaim: mongo-backup

resources:
  requests:
    memory: "2048Mi"

affinity:
  podAntiAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/instance
                operator: In
                values:
                  - mariadb
```

And these are the logs on startup

```
mongodb 15:31:22.69 INFO  ==> 
mongodb 15:31:22.70 INFO  ==> Welcome to the Bitnami mongodb container
mongodb 15:31:22.70 INFO  ==> Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
mongodb 15:31:22.70 INFO  ==> Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
mongodb 15:31:22.70 INFO  ==> 
mongodb 15:31:22.71 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB setup **
mongodb 15:31:22.73 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MONGODB_* env vars...
mongodb 15:31:22.80 INFO  ==> Initializing MongoDB...
mongodb 15:31:22.89 INFO  ==> Deploying MongoDB with persisted data...

mongodb 15:31:22.92 INFO  ==> ** MongoDB setup finished! **
mongodb 15:31:22.95 INFO  ==> ** Starting MongoDB **
{"t":{"$date":"2024-03-01T15:31:23.000Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5760901, "ctx":"main","msg":"Applied --setParameter options","attr":{"serverParameters":{"enableLocalhostAuthBypass":{"default":true,"value":false}}}}
```

I run this command to install the helm pod.

```
helm install mongodb-dump -f helm/mongodb-dump-2.yaml bitnami/mongodb --namespace temp-mongodump  --version 14.12.3
```

I have created the namespace, and I have a PV and a PVC configured. They seem to be working.

I have tried changing the version of bitnami/mongodb, but then I get other errors.

I am expecting the pod to start, and allow me access the mongodb database using the shell.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the error you are getting?